# Html 5 canvas and background

Tags: javascript, canvas

after trying a few ways to preserve a background under a canvas drawing a moving rectangle (animation code not reproduced), here is my best try :

```
canvas {background-image:url('background.png');}

var x,y, pixels;
function draw() {
  if(pixels) {
    context.putImageData(pixels,x,y);
  }
  x = //calculate new X
  y = //calculate new Y
  pixels = context.getImageData(x, y, 10, 10);
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
}
```

My first question is : why won't replacing the first two lines of draw() with :

```
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(10,10,10,0)';
context.fillRect(x,y,10,10);
```

work to clear the previously drawn pixels?

And my second question is : is there really no better way than get and putImageData(), which are very labor-intensive?

EDIT: in particular is there a div containing the background image trick that would maybe work without the get and putImageData calls?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, whatever you draw gets drawn on top of each other, instead of being replaced.

Use `context.clearRect(x,y,10,10);` instead.

There is also the `context.globalCompositeOperation` property, which could be set to `"destination-out"` before using `fillRect` .. but you're better off with `clearRect`.

Comment: Oh damn, of course. I have gone through so many iterations of trying to put a background under a canvas that I forgot this in the meantime. Thanks a lot!